# Microsoft Insight Java - Role name and instance in config file

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I got task to add Microsoft Insight to our API. In Api we have structure like this:

```
main
 profile
   demo.properties
   local.properties
   dev.properties
application.properties
```

I read in insight documentation that connection string, role etc can be different for each environment. I use connection string as environment variable, but I don't know how to achieve different role.name and role.instance for each environment and write it in these demo/local/dev.properties. If I could add connection string also to these properties it would be great

I was using applicationinsights.connection.string in local.properties, but it wasn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created separate properties files for each environment (`demo.properties`, `local.properties`, `dev.properties`).

[image]

**MyApp.java:**

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load configuration from demo.properties by default
        loadConfiguration("demo.properties");

        // Get configuration values
        String connectionString = AppConfig.getConnectionString();
        String roleName = AppConfig.getRoleName();
        String roleInstance = AppConfig.getRoleInstance();

        // Set up Application Insights with the configuration
        TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setInstrumentationKey(connectionString);

        // Simulate logging an event
        logEvent(roleName, roleInstance);
    }

    private static void loadConfiguration(String configFile) {
        try (InputStream input = MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFile)) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(input);

            // Set the configuration in the AppConfig class
            AppConfig.setConnectionString(properties.getProperty("applicationinsights.connection.string"));
            AppConfig.setRoleName(properties.getProperty("role.name"));
            AppConfig.setRoleInstance(properties.getProperty("role.instance"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void logEvent(String roleName, String roleInstance) {
        // Simulate logging an event with role and role instance information
        System.out.println("Logging event with Role: " + roleName + ", Role Instance: " + roleInstance);
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java:**

```java
public class AppConfig {
    private static String connectionString;
    private static String roleName;
    private static String roleInstance;

    public static String getConnectionString() {
        return connectionString;
    }

    public static void setConnectionString(String connectionString) {
        AppConfig.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public static String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public static void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        AppConfig.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public static String getRoleInstance() {
        return roleInstance;
    }

    public static void setRoleInstance(String roleInstance) {
        AppConfig.roleInstance = roleInstance;
    }
}
```

- The above application loads configuration from a specific properties file (`demo.properties` by default) and logs an event with role and role instance information.

[image]

I can see the appropriate logs generating as per my configuration.

Comment: Can you show me your pom.xml file for insight dependency? I can't find TelemetryConfiguration class in mine

Comment: Hi @SebastianHalik, I have used <version>3.4.18</version> `applicationinsights-web` to my application.